# How to make an imported module blit onto a surface from the main script?

Tags: python, module, pygame, undefined, blit

In my main file I have a surface called `win`. I import a module like so `from draw import *`.

```
def draw(image,x,y):
    win.blit(image,(x,y))
```

This is a function from `draw`. It doesn't work because `win` is not defined. How to make it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional parameter for the target surface to the function:

```py
def draw(target, image, x, y):
    target.blit(image, (x, y))
```

Pass `win` to the `draw` function:

```py
draw(win, image, x, y)
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a variable in the module's global namespace:

*draw.py*

```py
traget = None

def draw(image, x, y):
    traget.blit(image, (x, y))
```

Use the module:

```py
import pygame
import draw

# [...]

draw.target = win

# [...]

draw.draw(image, x, y)
```